# In the following code, I've been getting the following error: Test Failed: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python, debugging, calculator

This is my code I don't know where I'm doing it wrong

```
from stack import Stack
from simple_calculator import SimpleCalculator

class AdvancedCalculator(SimpleCalculator):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def tokenize(self, input_expression):
        import re
        tokens = re.findall(r"(\d+|[+\-*/(){}])", input_expression)
        return [int(token) if token.isdigit() else token for token in tokens]

    def check_brackets(self, list_tokens):
        bracket_stack = Stack()
        opening_brackets = ["(", "{", "["]
        closing_brackets = [")", "}", "]"]
        for token in list_tokens:
            if token in opening_brackets:
                bracket_stack.push(token)
            elif token in closing_brackets:
                if bracket_stack.is_empty():
                    return False
                top = bracket_stack.peek()
                if (token == ")" and top == "(") or (token == "}" and top == "{") or (token == "]" and top == "["):
                    bracket_stack.pop()
                else:
                    return False
        return bracket_stack.is_empty()

    def evaluate_list_tokens(self, list_tokens):
        operator_stack = Stack()
        operand_stack = Stack()
        for token in list_tokens:
            if isinstance(token, int):
                operand_stack.push(token)
            elif token in ["+", "-", "*", "/"]:
                while not operator_stack.is_empty() and self.has_higher_precedence(token, operator_stack.peek()):
                    operator = operator_stack.pop()
                    operand2 = operand_stack.pop()
                    operand1 = operand_stack.pop()
                    result = self.doeval(operand1, operator, operand2)
                    if result == "Error":
                        return "Error"
                    operand_stack.push(result)
                operator_stack.push(token)
            elif token in ["(", "{", "["]:
                operator_stack.push(token)
            elif token in [")", "}", "]"]:
                while not operator_stack.is_empty() and not operator_stack.peek() in ["(", "{", "["]:
                    operator = operator_stack.pop()
                    operand2 = operand_stack.pop()
                    operand1 = operand_stack.pop()
                    result = self.doeval(operand1, operator, operand2)
                    if result == "Error":
                        return "Error"
                    operand_stack.push(result)
                if not operator_stack.is_empty() and operator_stack.peek() in ["(", "{", "["]:
                    operator_stack.pop()

        while not operator_stack.is_empty():
            operator = operator_stack.pop()
            operand2 = operand_stack.pop()
            operand1 = operand_stack.pop()
            result = self.doeval(operand1, operator, operand2)
            if result == "Error":
                return "Error"
            operand_stack.push(result)

        return operand_stack.pop()

    def has_higher_precedence(self, op1, op2):
        precedence = {"+": 1, "-": 1, "*": 2, "/": 2}
        return precedence[op1] > precedence[op2]

    def doeval(self, a, b, c):
        a = int(a)
        c = int(c)
        if b == "+":
            return float(a) + float(c)
        elif b == "-":
            return float(a) - float(c)
        elif b == "*":
            return float(a) * float(c)
        elif b == "/":
            if c == 0:
                return "Error"
            return float(a) / float(c)
```

I firstly simply did a+b but looking in from some source it said do float(a)+float(b) and it would fix the problem but it still hasn't

Comment: could you pls post the entire stack trace?

Comment: There must be more code you haven't shown us.  This code _defines_ a class, but it's never actually _used_.

Comment: "and it would fix the problem but it still hasn't" - make sure to save your file and actually run that new file. Python doesn't automatically refresh the code. Otherwise this code is fine - so the only possibility is you not running updated file or some code you haven't shown us

Comment: https://github.com/ayushutd1/obscure-yodel  @JohnGordon I've added the link to entire code

Comment: _it said do float(a)+float(b) and it would fix the problem_ Why would doing `float()` for **addition** fix a problem with **subtraction**?

Comment: At the top of `doeval()`, you're already converting `a` and `c` into integers, so calling `float()` isn't really doing anything.

Comment: I tried without putting float but I still got same error how to fix it

Comment: @Kulasangar asked you to post the full stack trace error message.  Can you do that please?  And please add it to the question; don't post it as a comment.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We can't help you if you don't provide enough information to help you. For example, I have downloaded your code and run `calc.evaluate_expression("20 - 10")` and it works fine. I'm not going to now struggle to find where it does not work. It is your responsibility to provide the code and data that demonstrates the problem.